# rails admin error for rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I am cloning a new app from bitbucket, when I am trying to run `rake db:migrate`, I am getting the below errror.

> rake aborted! NameError: uninitialized constant RailsAdmin

I checked an answer where It is said that there's some path set for rails admin in the routes file, I need to remove the same from it.

```
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
```

This is part of my route file. Even If I am removing this line, I am getting the same error.

In another answer It said to upgrade rails, I did that as well, but it gives same error.

here's the complete error after I hit `rake db:migrate`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your gems are installed:

```
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: OMG, It worked. Bundle was obviously installed,

was trying `rake db:migrate` and was getting that error, I tried now `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, It worked. Crazy this is .

Comment: Well, you can accept an answer then :) Don't worry, it sometimes happens to the best of us.